# ERROR - com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas comunidad, estoy empezando a trabajar con la nueva Herramienta que ha incluido hace poco FireBase, me refiero a Cloud Firestore. Estoy intentando traerme una lista de documentos pero me da el siguiente error:

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.

En la siguiente línea de código:

```
 ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> documentos= (ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>) task.getResult().getDocuments();
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto que es algo nuevo, les dejo el código completo de la consulta, un saludo.

```
db.collection("incidencias").whereEqualTo("activa",true).limit(vez*5).orderBy("t_stamp").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> documentos= (ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>) task.getResult().getDocuments();

                    for(int i=0; i<documentos.size(); i++){
                        DocumentSnapshot datos=documentos.get(i);
                        IncidenciaItem incidenciaItem=new IncidenciaItem(datos.getString("titulo"),
                                datos.getDate("t_stamp"),datos.getString("usuario"),datos.getString("descripcion"),
                                datos.getString("img1"),datos.getString("img2"),datos.getString("img3"),
                                datos.getString("direccion"),datos.getGeoPoint("coordenadas"),String.valueOf(datos.getId()),
                                datos.getBoolean("activa"));

                        lista.add(incidenciaItem);

                    }

                    notificarCambio();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Agrega los indices, en el mensaje de error debe aparecer un enlace para ir a la consola de Firebase y agregarlos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero revisar la documentación acerca de [FAILED_PRECONDITION](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors)

> [FAILED_PRECONDITION](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors): Indica que no se cumplió una condición
>   previa para la solicitud. El campo de mensaje en la respuesta de error
>   proporciona información sobre la precondición que falló. Una causa
>   posible es ejecutar una consulta que requiere un índice aún no
>   definido.

En realidad **se requieren indices para esta consulta en Cloud Firestore**, debes realizarlo en la consola de Firebase, de hecho cuando se muestra el mensaje:

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException:
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.

debe aparecer un link el cual te lleva a la consola para realizar esta acción.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el fallo. Un saludo

Comment: Excelente, saludos Adrían!